# I'm trying to Calculate the amount to be charged for each assignment. Using Oracle DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this so far but stuck.....

```
SELECT a.Total_Assignment_Hrs, a.Assignment_Cost_Per_Day
SUM (Total_Assignment_Hrs-Assignment_Cost_Per_Day) AS Assignment_Cost
FROM Projects p,Employee_Records e, Assignments a
WHERE p.ProjectID=a.ProjectID
GROUP BY a.AssignmentID, a.Assignment_Name;
```

The issue i'm having is that i need to calculate the top SUM but i can't get it to produce a result with the sum statement in how do extend it to show what i need ?.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Please add the table structure and desired output.

Comment: Don't use Answer to simply add comments.  Answer is for people to actually answer your question.  Update your original post to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aXnC.png)

At the minute i can only get to here but need to calculate the total assignment hrs and assignment cost per day as a total

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the employee details from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT a.AssignmentID, a.Assignment_Name, 
       a.Assignment_Cost_Per_Day, p.Project_Name, a.Total_Assignment_Hrs,
       SUM (Total_Assignment_Hrs-Assignment_Cost_Per_Day) AS Assignment_Cost
  FROM Projects p JOIN Assignments a ON p.ProjectID=a.ProjectID 
  JOIN Employee_Records e ON <JOIN CONDITION>
GROUP BY a.AssignmentID, a.Assignment_Name, 
         a.Assignment_Cost_Per_Day, p.Project_Name, 
         a.Total_Assignment_Hrs;
```

**NOTE:** You are missing one join condition which I have marked as `ON <JOIN CONDITION>`